# How to compile google-fhir proto files

Tags: java, bazel, hl7-fhir, protocol-buffers

Looking at the readme for google-fhir it says to run `bazel build`, which works, however none of the protocol files have been compiled.

Running `protoc --proto_path=. --java_out=. proto/stu3/resources.proto` returns a bunch of error about other protos not being found. This goes backwards until 'descriptor.proto' which is not a proto in the folder. None of the protocol files in that directory will manually compile into java files.

*On another note, I was able to take other example protos from other sources and compile those successfully.

**UPDATE**

Running the command `protoc --proto_path=proto/stu3/ --java_out=target proto/stu3/resources.proto` from the google-fhir base directory returns the following output:

```
~/fhir-master$ protoc --proto_path=proto/stu3/ --java_out=target proto/stu3/resources.proto
proto/stu3/annotations.proto: File not found.
proto/stu3/codes.proto: File not found.
proto/stu3/datatypes.proto: File not found.
resources.proto: Import "proto/stu3/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors.
resources.proto: Import "proto/stu3/codes.proto" was not found or had errors.
resources.proto: Import "proto/stu3/datatypes.proto" was not found or had errors.
resources.proto:84:5: "String" is not defined.
resources.proto:87:14: "Extension" is not defined.
resources.proto:90:14: "Extension" is not defined.
resources.proto:94:5: "Reference" is not defined.
resources.proto:97:5: "PositiveInt" is not defined.
...
...
```

Those files are definitely located in the same proto directory.

**UPDATE 2**

Well, this definitely doesn't work right out of the box. Moving the files around, I was able to generate the target folder with a bunch of Java files. However, trying to compile them, I get errors for files that don't exist:

```
  symbol:   class CodeableConcept
  location: package com.google.fhir.stu3.proto
./PlanDefinition.java:30950: error: cannot find symbol
  public com.google.fhir.stu3.proto.CodeableConceptOrBuilder getJurisdictionOrBuilder(
                               ^
  symbol:   class CodeableConceptOrBuilder
  location: package com.google.fhir.stu3.proto
./PlanDefinition.java:30956: error: cannot find symbol
  private java.util.List<com.google.fhir.stu3.proto.CodeableConcept> topic_;
                                               ^
  symbol:   class CodeableConcept
  location: package com.google.fhir.stu3.proto
./PlanDefinition.java:30964: error: cannot find symbol
  public java.util.List<com.google.fhir.stu3.proto.CodeableConcept> getTopicList() {
                                              ^
  symbol:   class CodeableConcept
  location: package com.google.fhir.stu3.proto
./PlanDefinition.java:30974: error: cannot find symbol
  public java.util.List<? extends com.google.fhir.stu3.proto.CodeableConceptOrBuilder> 

  ....                                                         ^
  100 errors.
```

! Also, I don't see these file here: https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/java/core/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf

Comment: You should use Bazel to compile the protos.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: In the first sentence I mention using bazel successfully. It gives creates the following folders `bazel-bin  bazel-fhir-master  bazel-genfiles  bazel-out  bazel-testlogs  CONTRIBUTING.md  examples  java  LICENSE  proto  README.md  testdata  WORKSPACE`. However, there are no .java protocol buffer files.

Comment: Why do you need .java files? You should use Bazel to compile your Java code that consumes the protos.

Comment: I don't want anything in particular, I just want it to work. From what I understand, to work with protobuf in Java I need to generate builder files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like your command for compilation is not well formatted:
--proto_path=  This is the path to your proto
--java_out=  This is the folder where your class will be compiled

Your arguement is: proto/stu3/resources.proto, so I deduce that your files are located in proto/stu3.

Could you try this command and let us know if it worked for you:

```
protoc --proto_path=proto/stu3/ --java_out=target proto/stu3/resources.proto
```

If your proto descriptor are complete, you should have no compilation error, and your result should be in the folder "target".

EDIT:
looking at your latest edit, I would say that you should move resources.proto into your base directory and run the following command:
`protoc --proto_path=. --java_out=target resources.proto`

As the path to your import is coded in your import.
This is a bit difficult to help, as we don't have access to your entire proto descriptor. If you took it from an online repo, it would help if you could share it.

Comment: This is what I was doing, only from the proto directory. Tried from the base directory, see update above. Thanks.

Comment: Did you wrote the proto files yourself? You need to remove "proto/stu3/" in your import path. If all the files are located in the same directory.
Otherwise you need to move your root proto ("resources.proto")", to your root file, and use: protoc --proto_path=. --java_out=. resources.proto

Comment: No, I didn't write this myself. Thank you, your suggestion of the obvious worked and the Java files were generated. However I'm getting 100 compilation errors for files that don't exist in the folder. See update, and I can create a new question and mark this answered if you will look at it.

Comment: Sure, I will give a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010883/protocol-buffers-source-is-missing-files

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by not specifying a real path to the `--proto_path=` at all.

**How I did it**

- My folder structure looks like this: `D:\dev\OpenSourceProjects\` is my base folder.
- Within that folder, I have `google-fhir` which is my clone of the [github repo](https://github.com/google/fhir.git) and `protoc-3.11.3-win64` which is the unzip of the [protoc binaries](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.11.3/protoc-3.11.3-win64.zip)
- So for example, to build `resources.proto` run the following in `cmd`:

> `cd D:\dev\OpenSourceProjects\google-fhir`
>
> `D:\dev\OpenSourceProjects\protoc-3.11.3-win64\bin\protoc.exe --proto_path= --java_out=./proto/output .\proto\stu3\resources.proto`

- Note that `--proto_path=` is there, but empty and all other paths are relative