# Protocol Buffers source is missing files

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

For background, see: [How to compile google-fhir proto files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950107/how-to-compile-google-fhir-proto-files)

There seem to be missing .java files when compiling using protoc. I do not see those files here: https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/java/core/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf either. Of course, protoc generated additional files such a Patient.java that were not in the linked folder above. I just need it to compile.

```
  symbol:   class CodeableConcept
  location: package com.google.fhir.stu3.proto
./PlanDefinition.java:30950: error: cannot find symbol
  public com.google.fhir.stu3.proto.CodeableConceptOrBuilder getJurisdictionOrBuilder(
                               ^
  symbol:   class CodeableConceptOrBuilder
  location: package com.google.fhir.stu3.proto
./PlanDefinition.java:30956: error: cannot find symbol
  private java.util.List<com.google.fhir.stu3.proto.CodeableConcept> topic_;
                                               ^
  symbol:   class CodeableConcept
  location: package com.google.fhir.stu3.proto
./PlanDefinition.java:30964: error: cannot find symbol
  public java.util.List<com.google.fhir.stu3.proto.CodeableConcept> getTopicList() {
                                              ^
  symbol:   class CodeableConcept
  location: package com.google.fhir.stu3.proto
./PlanDefinition.java:30974: error: cannot find symbol
  public java.util.List<? extends com.google.fhir.stu3.proto.CodeableConceptOrBuilder> 

  ....                                                         ^
  100 errors.
```

**UPDATE**

Running examples/protogen/generate-proto.sh returns:

```
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
generate-descriptors.sh: line 29: ../../bazel-bin/java/ProtoGenerator: No such file or directory
```

It looks like bazel did not get run correctly, because ProtoGenerator is not in hazel-bin. I ran `bazel build`, in the root directory where there is a BUILD file. It complained about a workspace, to which I was told to create an empty WORKSPACE file. When done, there were no errors and bazel-bin was created. Are there additional parameters than `bazel build`. Also, I thought I saw more than one BUILD file in addition to the one in proto/stu3, but maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: When you run the example from the repo, is it working fine? https://github.com/google/fhir/blob/master/examples/protogen/generate-proto.sh I just cloned it, and on my side this is ok.

Comment: Do I need to run generate-descriptors.sh before generate-proto.sh? Or does it not matter?

Comment: They are only example. If the example are running, it means that your environment is well set-up.